# OS 10.9.1 didReceiveReadRequest not getting called

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-bluetooth

In my continued quest to make a MacBook appear like one of my real peripherals, for testing purposes, I am discovering that `didReceiveReadRequest` isn't getting called.

How does a `CBMutableCharacteristic` have to be configured, so that when it is read, a call to `didReceiveReadRequest` results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set `nil` as the `value` at the characteristic initialization. This way it becomes a dynamic characteristic. This is described in detail [in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBMutableCharacteristic_Class/Reference/CBMutableCharacteristic.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBMutableCharacteristic/initWithType%3aproperties%3avalue%3apermissions%3a).

```
[[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:MY_UUID]
                                   properties: CBCharacteristicPropertyRead|CBCharacteristicPropertyIndicate
                                        value:nil  // this is the critical part
                                  permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];
```

You can find other samples, for example, in this project: [AttackPattern/BlueSim](https://github.com/AttackPattern/BlueSim)